# Why does tidyverse installation not find packages on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, tidyverse

On a machine running Ubuntu 18.04 and R version 3.6.1 I can't install tidyverse:

> install.packages("tidyverse")

```
Installing package into ‘/home/abraji/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’, ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’

tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 379180 bytes (370 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 370 KB

tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/openssl_1.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1206885 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/httr_1.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 158465 bytes (154 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 154 KB

tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rvest_0.3.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1631028 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/xml2_1.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 261081 bytes (254 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 254 KB

tentando a URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 61647 bytes (60 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 60 KB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/abraji/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/abraji/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lxml2
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libxml2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libxml2_dev (Solaris)
If libxml-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libxml-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/abraji/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/abraji/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘httr’ are not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/abraji/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rvest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/abraji/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmppDajwu/downloaded_packages’
```

Installation does not seem to recognize or find packages

Installation is being done from RStudio

Also tried with dependencies = TRUE but errors persist

Please does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: It says `libxml-2.0` not found.  You may need to iinstall with `sudo`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't install devtools either @akrun

Comment: look at the second answer at that link (@ilona's)

Comment: The error messages tell you what to install. Stuff like `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` If you can't install the necessary dependencies on your machine, you simply cannot install these packages.

Comment: Thank you all. I installed libcurl4-openssl-dev and then the installation worked